# I want to fetch data and display it in a react page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm new to reactjs, I want to fetch and display data from my database table in a react page ,i wrote a code following a tutorial but i don't know how to correct it.
This is the data :
[image]

and this is the code i'm writing

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Companies() {
   const [companies, setCompanies] = useState(initialState: [])

   useEffect( effect: () => {
      companydata()
      },   deps: [])

   const companydata = async () => {
      const {data}= await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/companies");

      setCompanies(data);
   }

   return (
      <div className="companies">
         {companies.map(companies => (
         <div key={companies.CompanyId}>
            <h5>{companies.CompanyName}</h5>
            </div>
            ))}

      </div>
   );
         }

export default Companies;
```

Comment: In `useState` you just need to write this:  `const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([])`

Comment: in your useEffect, no need to write `deps: []`, just put an empty array:
   ```useEffect( () => {
      companydata()
      },   [])```
also, remove the `effect: `

Comment: and `companydata` should be declared before useEffect, for hoisting matters, or declared as a `async function companydata` if you want to declare it after.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect( effect: async () => {
      await companydata()
      },   deps: [])
```

have you tried adding `async` and `await` inside useEffect hook